# redirect page to difference server in php

Tags: php

Does anyone know the code used for redirect page to difference server in PHP?

For example: I have 3 server here called server_1, server_2, server_3. and I would like to redirect a page abc.php to server_2. How should the code look like in php?

Comment: you have a specific url you want it to point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("Location: http://server_2/abc.php");
```